# Passing variables to directives in AngularJS without a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a simple navbar directive that I published to NPM and injected into my main project as a node module. The nav directive has a `sitemap` attribute that takes an object as a parameter. This object maps out the site links and names of the links to dynamically create the navbar. I'd like to be able to set the sitemap object in my main AngularJS project as a constant or something similar, and be able to pass it in anywhere the nav is used without injecting it into a controller, because many of my views don't actually need controllers. How can I access a variable in a view that doesn't have a controller?

Comment: A quick google of "angular directive without controller" led me to this: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a top-level controller, you can define the sitemap as a property in the top-level scope and child scopes should be able to access that property thanks to prototypal inheritance.

Another pattern you can apply is to define a provider for your directive that can be used at the configuration phase to define a sitemap. Then you don't have to use an attribute to pass the sitemap to your directive. Something like:

```
angular
    .module('awesomeSitemap', [])
    .provider('sitemapData', function () {
        var sitemapData;

        this.setSitemapData = function (_sitemapData) {
            sitemapData = _sitemapData;
        };

        this.$get = function () {
            return sitemapData;
        };
    })
    .directive('sitemap', [ 'sitemapData', function (sitemapData) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: sitemapTmpl,
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.sitemapData = sitemapData;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Then in your app:

```
angular
    .module('app', [ 'awesomeSitemap' ])
    .config([ 'sitemapDataProvider', function (sitemapDataProvider) {
        sitemapDataProvider.setSitemapData(theSitemapData);
    }]);
```

Comment: I used the provider pattern and it worked perfectly, thanks!